# Parsing string to array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to parse a string in to an array with specific delimiters but its not working as expected. I tried a lot to get this working but failed.

Code i am using is below.

**CODE TO PARSE**

```
        char itemCode[] = "0xFF,0xAA,0xBB,0x00,0x01,0x04,0x90";
        char itemCodeToSend[34] = {0};
        char ** res  = NULL;
        char *  p    = strtok (itemCode, ",");
        int n_spaces = 0, i; 

        /* split string and append tokens to 'res' and 'itemCodeToSend' */

        while (p) {
          res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);

          if (res == NULL)
            exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

          res[n_spaces-1] = p; // Copying to char**
          strcpy(&itemCodeToSend[0],p);// Copying to Array

          p = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }

        /* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */

        res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
        res[n_spaces] = 0;

        /* print the result */

        for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces); ++i)
          printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, res[i]);

                    for (i = 0; i < 34; ++i)
          printf ("0x%02x",(unsigned)res[i]&0xffU);

        /* free the memory allocated */ 
        free (res);
```

I am getting the below output for `char**` but not for `char[]`

```
res[0] = "0xFF";    itemCodeToSend[0] = "0x30";
res[1] = "0xAA";    itemCodeToSend[1] = "0x30";
res[2] = "0xBB";    itemCodeToSend[2] = "0x30";
res[3] = "0x00";    itemCodeToSend[3] = "0x30";
res[4] = "0x01";    itemCodeToSend[4] = "0x30";
res[5] = "0x04";    itemCodeToSend[5] = "0x30";
res[6] = "0x90";    itemCodeToSend[6] = "0x30";
```

Am i using right way to copy the extracted value to array?

Comment: 'What i am doing wrong here?' - not debugging.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about NO ATTEMPT AT DEBUGGING.

Comment: @MartinJames I tried a lot to get this working but couldn't find the solution. That's why posted the question

Comment: `0x30` = ASCII for "0", if this helps you debug.

Comment: @ccKep Thanks. Am i am using right way to copy the value to array `strcpy(&itemCodeToSend[0],p);`

Comment: Unrelated, but think about what would happen if `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`. Then `res` would be `NULL` as well and you will loose the pointer to the already allocated memory.

Comment: What is the expected result for `itemCodeToSend[1]` etc.?

Comment: The same as res[0] in left side

Comment: @JoachimPileborg He already handles that case with `exit(-1)`.

Comment: @ccKep It's handled in that case only, there is another `realloc` call where it's not handled.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Indeed, pardon me. On Topic Vino: If you want the characters inside `itemCodeToSend` to represent the hex values in your string you need to somehow parse them (`strtol` as suggested below, `sscanf` might do aswell). At the moment you are just copying the first char (which is always a "0" cause all your entries start with "0x").

Comment: @Holt sorry its my mistake while copying the code in SO

Comment: @Vino NP, i think you got your answer bellow. Just a small trick to output `0x` for your hexa: `printf("%#02x", ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want these lines to access `itemCodeToSend`.

```
                for (i = 0; i < 34; ++i)
      printf ("0x%02x",(unsigned)res[j]&0xffU);
```

Before that, you you write to `itemCodeToSend` it looks like you
want to write the integer values, not their textual representation. And not to overwrite
the same element in each loop.

Perhaps you need something along the lines of

```
itemCodeToSend[n_spaces-1] = strtol(p, 0, 16);
```

or similar, instead of

```
strcpy(&itemCodeToSend[0],p);// Copying to Array
```

Comment: Thanks chill. This is what i am looking for. I spent over 5 hours just in this. Much Appreciated